# Difference between HTML and Script in Firebug

Tags: html, firebug

I was going through a webpage and searched Google on how to find the page information.

I installed Firebug and there I found two things. The first is the HTML option and the second the Script option.

What is the difference between these two things? When I am looking at the page source it is exactly matching with the Script content shown in the Firebug. Then what is the code shown in the HTML option?

Answer (score 0):

These "options" are actually called "panels".

The *HTML* panel allows you to inspect and change the HTML structure of the page. It is a live view of what is displayed on the page and provides you with different information related to the selected HTML element like applying CSS or its DOM properties. You can read more about the *HTML* panel here:

https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/HTML_Panel

In contrary the code you get via the page's context menu option *View Source* is just a static view of the code when the page was requested from the server.

The *Script* panel is used for JavaScript debugging. It allows you to set breakpoints to stop the script execution at them. When the script is halted you can view the stack trace and the variables available in the current stack frame. You can read more about the *Script* panel here:

https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Script_Panel

Answer (score 0):

HTML Panel shows you the generated source of the page. This content can be different from what you see when you do a view source of the page. This pages shows you the DOM of the page. The Script Panel is something used to debug javaScript that generates the DOM. You can set break points and see the call stack on the right hand side pane of the Script panel. While as Right hand side panel of HTML block shows the CSS rules used to style DOM elements.